# URL Rewrite (1.9) - more then one Request Path

Tags: magento-1.9, url-rewrite

Is it posible to add more then one request path but same target,  http://prntscr.com/qbhr6e , i tried with just space, coma... I use 1.9 ver...

Comment: I think you should try with another new rewrite rule to add  another request path but with same target path. have you tried it ?

Comment: I have tried it, but i get error ID Path for Specified Store already exists.